# Retrieve Numbers After Certain Part of String

Tags: php, sql

I know there are a couple of posts on here but I can't quite apply them to what I am looking for.  I have a column in the database that is called UF_CRM_TASK.  It contains differing values that look like:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"C_8";i:1;s:4:"CO_6";}

SELECT UF_CRM_TASK FROM b_uts_tasks_task
```

I need the number that always follows CO_.  Sometimes the number might be 1,2,3,4 or 5 figures long. So for example CO_22 or CO_348 or CO_8374

I need to echo the out in PHP.  If somebody could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this using `substring_index()` and silent conversion:

```
select substring_index(UF_CRM_TASK, 'CO_', -1) + 0
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/45307) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Oops, off by 3 ;)  The query is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = 'a:2:{i:0;s:3:"C_8";i:1;s:4:"CO_6";}';
$pos  = strpos($a,'CO_');
$pos1 = strpos($a,'"',$pos);
$len = $pos1-($pos+3);
$str = substr($a,$pos+3,$len);
echo $str;
?>
```

$a will be the value you fetch from database
this can help